# react-native debug - what do n, r and t mean

Tags: react-native

My app has a crash issue and sent the crash log to Fabric. I am having trouble to read the log.

[image]

Obviously, I did not use n or t as my function, variable or object name. I would like to know what do these single characters mean in react native.

Comment: They're minified variable names

Comment: How to know what are replaced by those minified variable names